# Storing time_t within std::string fails

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

Okay may not be the best title but I'm trying to determine what the issue is. I have s valid char* that contains a long variable when I read this in it is correct, lastSaveTime is valid. Everything is valid until the IF statement. Once this happens the seconds variable becomes either corrupt or bad. In the watch window it show nothing and when I use seconds later it doesn't actually contain valid data and therefor is bad.

Any suggestions?

```
time_t lastSaveTime;
lastSaveTime = static_cast<time_t>(atol(lastTime.c_str()));

time_t nowTime;
time(&nowTime);

double seconds = difftime(nowTime, lastSaveTime);

if (seconds > 86400)
{
    seconds = 86400;
}
```

Comment: That is *not* the way to convert data pointed to by a `const char*` to a `time_t`. Try a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)

Comment: For my original question I believe I have found the issue. Not 100% familiar with Xcode and iOS and found that std::numeric_limits<long>::max() is a lot smaller when I just ran it: 2147483647 I was expecting a much larger number: 9223372036854775807 which is a long long... my bad